# Please explain one VAST 2.0 scenario

Tags: video, ads, vast

I'm trying to understand the sequence of actions the media player must execute when playing this sample VAST 2.0: http://demo.tremorvideo.com/proddev/vast/vast_wrapper_linear_1.xml.

Several moments I don't understand:

1. Ad the wrapper links on contains 2 creatives. Movie player must play each of them consistently or play the first one only?
2. Wrapper contains 3 creatives, but the Ad it links on contains only 2 creatives. I don't understand how to share tracking events from Wrapper among creatives from Ad.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Yes, there are two creatives, but they have different types: Linear and Companion. They both should be played simultaneously. Linear creative is played inside the media player and the companion creative (actually there are two companions) are shown in separate slots outside the media player.

Please, see how your VAST is played in this VAST validator: http://www.adopsforums.com/adops-tools/vast-validator

2 You should share tracking events according to creative type. In the wrapper VAST we have two Linear creatives and one nonLinear creative. In the wrapped VAST (http://demo.tremormedia.com/proddev/vast/vast_inline_linear.xml) we don't have non linear creatives, so we should not share anything (actually there are no tracking events for non linear creative in the wrapper VAST). 
Linear creative is present in the wrapped VAST, so all tracking events from the wrapper VAST should be shared.

Answer (score 0):

**[1]** A VAST ( Video Ad Serving Template ) is a single AD definition.**The VAST will only contain one Video AD** but it might include a couple of MediaFile Tags that serve as different sources for the same video.

In the example you attached the Linear VAST that's wrapped inside is containing Linear and Non-linear creatives whereas the Linear referrers to the Video File and the Non-linear is referring to the two banner creatives.

Usually, in an AD playback the Non-Linear creatives are displayed along side to the video player during the ad playback in case of a matching companion ad container.

**[2]** A valid wrapper VAST should contain a MAX tracking events equivalent to the even beacons that are present in the wrapped Inline VAST. Like @askalozubov mentions, in the example VAST you used there are no wrapper tracking beacons and so the tracking beacons for these events will only be sent out to the Primary Ad Server. Please Note that basically all that a wrapper does is attaching more tracking beacons to the existing Inline VAST.

Here's another nice VPAID-VAST Validator : http://tools.playitviral.com/vast-validator